# IE object tag alternate content not showing

Tags: html, xhtml

I am using the xhtml valid way to embed below:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="360" data="youtube-video-url">
    <param name="movie" value="youtube-video-url" />
    <param name="allscriptaccess" value="always" />
    <p>Adobe Flash is required to view this content. Please <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">download Flash Player</a>.</p>
</object>
```

When I view it in IE without flash installed, I just get a black box and no alternate content. If I take out the type="application/x-shockwave-flash" attribute, the alternate content will appear. Why is it not showing the alternate content when the type attribute is specified and how do I correct this?

Comment: This only seems to happen when the type attribute is set to "application/x-shockwave-flash". If I set the type attribute to "application/x-java-applet", it will display the fallback content.

Comment: It only seems to happen on Windows XP. Vista correctly displays the alternate content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find a solution to this problem. It only happened in Windows XP when the type was set to "application/x-shockwave-flash".

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support fallback of the object element. What you describe should happen but IE is well, IE. You could use SWFObject to embed the flash if you really like a fallback.

Comment: The strange part is that it does support fallback when the type attribute is not specified, but then it doesn't work when flash is available.

Comment: IE decides that if an object can't be shown, it doesn't exist. If you check you'll see the the object is no longer part of the DOM.

Comment: IE does support object fallback http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304133%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#Fallback

Comment: The object is no longer part of the DOM, but the inner HTML of the object has replaced the object in the DOM. If the type is set to "application/x-shockwave-flash", the object tag is part of the DOM even though flash is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the data parameter from the  tag. It will work that way. Then if you put it back, you will notice that you might not be able to reproduce this issue. Also, try removing  and using only data. You will find the possibilities interesting.